# Bash code to install bootstrap in a Ruby on Rails repository

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Wrote some code to install bootstrap (latest) in a newly created rails application.

update: fixed a typo

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js expose-loader
yarn install --check-files
perl -pi.bak -e "s/extract_css: false/extract_css: true/" config/webpacker.yml
s1=$'\n\nimport "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";'
echo "$s1" >> app/javascript/packs/application.js
echo '@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";' > app/javascript/packs/styles.scss
(gsed $'/module.exports = environment/{e cat expose-loader.txt\n}' config/webpack/environment.js) > config/webpack/environment.js.new
mv config/webpack/environment.js.new config/webpack/environment.js
(gsed $'/javascript_pack_tag .application/{e cat stylesheet_pack_tag.txt\n}' app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) > app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.new
mv app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.new app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Answer (score 4):

It's worth starting with a shebang; I'd also advise setting shell flags `-e` (exit on error) and `-u` (error when using unset variables):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
```

Please use more whitespace and comments to make it easier to follow.

Perl is overkill for the simple substitution here - if we stick to sed, then that's one fewer dependency:

```
sed -e '/^extract_css:/:.*/ true/' \
    -i config/webpacker.yml
```

I omitted creating the backup because I don't think there's any value in keeping the original.  If your later processes depend on having it around, then use `-i.bak` instead of `-i`, as in Perl (in fact, that's where Perl got that option).

The two transform-and-move pairs can also use `sed -i`, making the script more consistent, and thus easier to follow.  We can use the (standard sed) `r` command to read a file, instead of the non-standard `e` command:

```
sed -e '/module.exports = environment/rexpose-loader.txt' \
    -i config/webpack/environment.js
sed -e '/javascript_pack_tag .application/rstylesheet_pack_tag.txt' \
    -i app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

`$s1` is only used once, and doesn't add any value (such as a meaningful name), so just inline it.

If we can eliminate the one use of C-escape quoting, then we can use plain POSIX shell instead of Bash.

---

## Modified code

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js expose-loader
yarn install --check-files

sed -e '/^extract_css:/:.*/ true/' \
    -i config/webpacker.yml

printf '\n\n%s' 'import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";' \
       >> app/javascript/packs/application.js
echo '@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";' \
     > app/javascript/packs/styles.scss

sed -e '/module.exports = environment/rexpose-loader.txt' \
    -i config/webpack/environment.js
sed -e '/javascript_pack_tag .application/rstylesheet_pack_tag.txt' \
    -i app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

In the two uses of `( )`, you have single commands:

> ```
> (gsed $'/module.exports = environment/{e cat expose-loader.txt\n}' config/webpack/environment.js) > config/webpack/environment.js.new
>  ...
> (gsed $'/javascript_pack_tag .application/{e cat stylesheet_pack_tag.txt\n}' app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) > app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.new
> ```

These could be written as:

```
gsed $'/module.exports = environment/{e cat expose-loader.txt\n}' config/webpack/environment.js > config/webpack/environment.js.new
...
gsed $'/javascript_pack_tag .application/{e cat stylesheet_pack_tag.txt\n}' app/views/layouts/application.html.erb > app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.new
```